# how to get the value of a custom element with angular 2

Tags: angular

I have this, https://embed.plnkr.co/xXt9wKs7jzpaivQeLjbx/
the calendar is my custom component, but if I show 
{{dateValue | date:"yyyy/MM/dd"}}
this is not getting the selected date I am choosing in my calendar.

How can I get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `@Output` property to your `FxDatePickerComponent`:

```
@Output() valueChange: EventEmitter<Date> = new EventEmitter();
```

then you can use two-way binding in template:

```
<fx-datepicker [(value)]="dateValue"></fx-datepicker>
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/BlUtyZwEJi1B029oI4zT?p=preview)**

Answer (score 1):

.Have you tried somethng like:

in your (app.component.html) `HTML:`

```
(dateModelChange)="countChange($event)"
```

In your `TS (App.compoment.ts):`

```
countChange(event){
   this.dateValue=event;
 }
```

Cuase you need to declare also the 'listener' to the @output property .. so you're right to declare :

```
 @Output() dateModelChange: EventEmitter<Date> = new EventEmitter();
```

In your sub component .. but you'have also to declare  a `listener`  to it in the `parent component`